# Unable to use AFNetworking in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

The problem is that the server is returning json object but says that "please select a file" , even though I am passing the data as NSData by calling the function **appendPartWithFormData** .

Please help me out here , I am stuck on this part for a long time .

Thank you

```
// Defining dictionary parameters
NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:regId forKey:@"id"];
[_params setObject:email forKey:@"email"];
[_params setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
[_params setObject:_formatedDate forKey:@"datesel"];
[_params setObject:self.documentDescription.text forKey:@"description"];
[_params setObject:self.documentName.text forKey:@"name"];
[_params setObject:self.documentType.text forKey:@"type"];
[_params setObject:@"no" forKey:@"isDepedent"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.finalImage.image, 1.0);


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:url parameters:_params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
{
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"image"];
}success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success %@",responseObject);

    UIAlertView *Alert_Success_fail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"myappname" message:string delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [Alert_Success_fail show];
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Fail ");

    UIAlertView *Alert_Success_fail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"myappname" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [Alert_Success_fail show];
}];



OUTPUT - Success {
    data =     {
        message = "Please select file.";
       status = 0;
    };
 }
```

Comment: First check, whether your Post request is working fine in Postman ,https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en     If you get the same response there , then there is problem from your back end , if you get success there then try to debug your code.

Comment: `po imagedata` is not nil?

Comment: This is entirely contingent on what your server expects. There's no way to tell whether the client code is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the image as a file,then upload the file.
AFNetWorkSample：

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

if it's not work,there may be something wrong with your server.

Comment: This is not working , and the server is fine since android app is successfully uploading image.